# Removing additive factors from the denominator of a fraction

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

Suppose I have a variable $x_L$ defined as follows:

$$
x_L=\frac{r_1e^{-t_0s}}{s + r_2 + r_3},
$$

Is there a way for me to rearrange this fraction to get something in this form

$$
x_L = [\operatorname{stuff}] \ldots \frac{[\operatorname{stuff}]}{s},
$$

where "$\ldots$" is any operator (e.g., $+$ or $\times$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wanted:

\begin{align}
x_L&=\frac{r_1e^{-t_0s}}{s}\bigg(\frac{1}{1 + r_2/s + r_3/s}\bigg)\\
x_L&=\frac{r_1e^{-t_0s}}{s}\bigg(\frac{s}{s + r_2 + r_3}\bigg)\\
x_L&=\frac{r_1e^{-t_0s}}{s}\bigg(\frac{1}{s + r_2 + r_3}\bigg)s\\
x_L&=r_1e^{-t_0s}\bigg(\frac{1}{s + r_2 + r_3}\bigg)
\end{align}